# React Chart.js BarGraph not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-chartjs-2

I'm trying to implement a bar chart using `react-chartjs-2`, but I have some problems passing data to it.

If I declare the array directly when calling the graph, it works:

```js
render(){
      return(
        <div>
          <NumberField label={"n"} min={0} max={9999999} handleChange={this.changeN}/>
          <NumberField label={"p"} min={0} max={1} handleChange={this.changeP}/>
          <Distribution name={this.state.name} 
            media={this.state.media} 
            varianza={this.state.varianza}
            desviacion={this.state.desviacion}
          />
          <BarGraph _labels={['a','b']} _data= {[1,2]}/>
          
        </div>
      )
    }
```

[first way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DhaE.png)

but if I try something like:

```js
constructor (props) {
      super(props);
      this.changeN = this.changeN.bind(this);
      this.changeP = this.changeP.bind(this);

      this.state={
        name: "Binomial",
        p: 0,
        n: 0,
        media: 0,
        varianza: 0,
        desviacion: 0,
        labels: [],
        data: []
      }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(_prevProps, prevState) {
      if (prevState.p !== this.state.p || prevState.n !== this.state.n) {
        
        this.setState({
          media: this.calcularMedia(),
          varianza: this.calcularVarianza(),
          desviacion: this.calcularDesviacion(),
          data: [1,2],
          labels: ['a', 'b']
        });
      }
    }

·········

render(){
      return(
        <div>
          <NumberField label={"n"} min={0} max={9999999} handleChange={this.changeN}/>
          <NumberField label={"p"} min={0} max={1} handleChange={this.changeP}/>
          <Distribution name={this.state.name} 
            media={this.state.media} 
            varianza={this.state.varianza}
            desviacion={this.state.desviacion}
          />
          <BarGraph _labels={this.state.labels} _data= {this.state.data}/>
          
        </div>
      )
    }
```

the graph won't render correctly: [second way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbdBW.png)

This is the BarGraph component:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {Bar} from 'react-chartjs-2';

const BarGraph = ({_labels, _data}) =>{
    const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({});

    const chart = () =>{
        setChartData({
            labels: _labels,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'label',
                    data: _data,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192, 0.6)',
                    highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            ]
        })
    }

    useEffect(()=> {
        chart()
    }, [])


    return(
        <div className="App">
        <div style={{height: "500px", width: "500px"}}>
            <Bar data={chartData} options={{
                legend:{
                    display: false
                },
               responsive: true,
               title: {text: 'title', display: true},
               scales:{
                   yAxes:[
                       {
                           ticks:{
                               autoSkip: true,
                               maxTicksLimit: 10,
                               beginAtZero: true
                           }
                       }
                   ]
               }
            }}/>
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default BarGraph;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error you're getting? I would try to add some conditional logic, to just display the bar if there's data in the array.

Comment: I'm not getting any compiling error, it's just that passing the data like in the second way the graph is empty. I'll add some photos in the problem description.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the data in the main file and passing it works fine:

```js
const graphData= {
  labels: ['t1', 't2'],
  datasets: [
    {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(90, 172, 170, 0.8)',
      data: [15,78]
    }
  ]
}

class Binomial extends Component {
render(){
      console.log(this.state.data);
      console.log(this.state.labels);
      return(
        <div>
          <BarGraph3 data={graphData}/>
        </div>
      )
    }
}
}
```